# How can I output multiple sprite sheets from a single .fla?

Tags: actionscript-3, spritesheet

I have to produce out three sprite sheets of differing sizes. To do so, I have three different `.fla` source files.

Obviously maintaining three files takes more time than maintaining one; is there some way that I can use one `.fla` and produce three differently-sized sprite sheets?

Answer (score 2):

Use key frames to your advantage

Combine you `.fla` files into one `.fla` by putting each separate sprite sheet on a key frame, then copy those frames and scale them to get your extra sizes.

You will then have a sequence of all your sprite sheets and different sizes on your timeline. Make sure your stage is big enough for your largest sheet then export movie as a `.png` sequence.

You will have to crop the smaller sizes, but in the process you will be able to optimize and index the colours on the sheets which may save you some more memory.